# How do I enable vtx to install haxm for Android studio

Tags: windows-10, vt-x, intel-haxm

I'm a new Android developer and as I was getting set up I had to install haxm but I'd gives me an error when I run the installation
I'm running Windows 10 on a HP probook 6460b. Help? anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable **VT-x** from **BIOS** of your computer.

1. Reboot laptop and use ‘**Escape**’ to bring up boot menu
2. Key ‘**F10**’ to enter the **BIOS** Setup
3. Hit Tab key twice to move to ‘**System Configuration**’ options
4. Ensure that the ‘**Virtualization Technology**’ checkbox is checked
5. Press **F10** to Save and Exit
6. Continue with laptop boot and **VT-x** should be enabled now

Comment: I did and the installation stop gives me the same thing...